# How to use jsFiddle code on Notepad Php file

Tags: php, jquery, jsfiddle

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNxBy/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        $('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>

<select id="2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

I want to apply this code in my php file and i haven't studied jQuery so i copy pasted the code on my notepad saved it with .php extension and ran it on localhost but only html part is running and the script is not working. Please help i know its a childish question but i am trying to learn.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I recommend first learning what is jQuery and javascript and learn what the code does before trying to use it. It's not possible to skip these steps if you want to learn and actually use the code. Just throwing random bits of code in a html-file is not going to get you anywhere. You can start learning about jQuery here: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and try and use js extension and include it in your php

Answer (score 1):

add this code to php or html file 
and run

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>

<select id="2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
        $('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
</script>
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

In which `php` file did you copy the code ? .

First , you need to include jQuery. For example  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` ( which is the latest ) in `footer.php` just before the closing `<body>` tag

Then you can put the javascript/jquery code either in a separate file with `.js` extension and then call it in `footer.php` before the closing of `body` tag. ( after the jQuery call )  Something like so `<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScripts.js"></script>` // i suggest this approach for cleaner and easier to use/manage/change code

Or you can put it in `header.php` inside the `<head>` tag , but you need to wrap it inside `<script> .... </script>` So it will look something like

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
       your code here
 });
</script>
```